# WPF open new Mahapps window with GlowBrush

Tags: border, mahapps.metro, glow

I would like to open a new MetroWindow (Mahapps) with border glow from C# code. I succeded to do that from xaml with the GlowBrush property, but couldn't achived the same result from C# code.

Here is how I tried:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MetroWindow window = new MetroWindow()
        {
            Title = "XY",
            ShowTitleBar = false,
            GlowBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DodgerBlue),
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResize,
            WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen,
        };

        window.Show();
    }
```

The window opens borderless without any glowing effect.
Could anyone please help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: which version have you installed? i have no problem with the latest version 1.1.2

Comment: Thanks for the advise! You were right, I used a way too old version of Mahapps. Sorry I thought I had done something wrong and it is not a bug. Thanks for the help!